# Passing arguments to wkhtmltopdf using GoLang

Tags: go, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to develop a small app to convert html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf and GoLang. But when I try to pass arguments to it, getting an exit status of 1.

> > args := []string{"--page-height 420mm","--page-width 297mm","/path/src/edit.html","/path/src/edit.pdf"}
> >         fmt.Println(args)
> >         cmd := exec.Command("/home/local/ZOHOCORP/santhosh-4759/Downloads/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf",args...)
> >         fmt.Println(cmd)

Ouptut of cmd and args

> > **cmd:**
> >     &{/path/wkhtmltopdf [/path/wkhtmltopdf --page-height 420mm --page-width 297mm /path/src/edit.html /path/src/edit.pdf] []     []      false [] [] [] []  }
> >
> > **args**[--page-height 420mm --page-width 297mm /path/src/edit.html /path/src/edit.pdf]

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, you'll have to replace the paths with yours

```
args := []string{"./wkhtmltopdfTest/edit.html","./wkhtmltopdfTest/edit.pdf"}
cmd := exec.Command("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf",args...)

out,err := cmd.CombinedOutput()

if err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("PDF succesfully generated")
} else {
    fmt.Printf("Error: %s %s", err, out)
}
```

If it's good, you can add the --page arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can use Go binding for `wkhtmltopdf`. Check [this](https://github.com/pleximus/go-htmltopdf)